# A.s. convergence of densities implies convergence in distribution?

Tags: probability-theory

> **Problem.** Let $X,X_1,X_2,...$ be random variables with distribution functions $F, F_1, F_2,...$ and $\lambda_1$ densities $f, f_1,f_2,..$ respectively. Is it true that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n = f \text{ a.s.} \implies X_n\to_dX?$$
>   Is the converse true?

I think that "$\implies$" is true and the converse is false.

Suppose $f_n\to f$ a.s. By Polya's theorem, $X_n\to_dX$ is equivalent to $\sup_{x\in \Bbb R} |F_n(x) - F(x)| \to 0$, so let's try to show that.

$$\begin{eqnarray} \sup_{x\in \Bbb R} |F_n(x) - F(x)|&=&\sup_{x\in \Bbb R} \left| \int_{(-\infty,x)}f_n(t)dt - \int_{(-\infty,x)}f(t)dt\right|
\\&\leq& \sup_{x\in \Bbb R} \int_{(-\infty, x)}|f_n(t)-f(t)| dt
\\&=& \int_{\Bbb R}|f_n(t)-f(t)| dt
\end{eqnarray}$$
which converges to $0$ as $n\to \infty$ by Scheffé's Lemma.

Is that an acceptable proof for "$\implies$"?
I was not able to prove the converse, nor find a counter example to it, but I suspect it is false. Could you please share a hint?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By Scheffé's lemma, the almost everywhere convergence of densities implies the convergence of the corresponding measures in total variation, see, for instance, [Lemma 2.2 here](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Earinaldo/36789/Oct29.pdf). Of course, convergence in total variation is stronger than convergence in distribution, for example see [the discussion here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures).

Comment: Link to first paper is broken.

Answer (score 5):

As for a converse result, in the following references:

https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aos/1176346604

https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aos/1176350065

pointwise convergence on densities is obtained from weak convergence of the corresponding probability measures, under suitable equicontinuity assumptions on the sequence of densities.